# Listing files with numeric names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How do I list files that have only numeric names e.g

```
1111 
2342 
763
71
```

I have tried  `ls -l [0-9]*`   but this seems to bring all file names that
start with a digit and  can have anything in their name after a digit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, turn on Bash's `extglob` option:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then use this pattern:

```
ls -l +([0-9])
```

Read more about extended pattern matching in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).

Comment: Thanks rob! to extend my problem further I tried  to rename files matching the patter as `rename 's/$/.ext/' +([0-9])` but this does not seem to work , would you be able to guide whats wrong ?

Comment: I don't know what `rename` command you're using. You should probably post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `find`:

```
find . -type f -regex './[0-9]*$'
```

This uses a regular expression rather than a filename globbing pattern. The expression `./[0-9]*$` matches `./` (the current directory) followed by only digits until the end (`$`).

If you need to stop `find` from going into subdirectories, add `-maxdepth 1`.

If you want `ls -l` -like behaviour, add `-ls` at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

With opposite operation : ignoring filenames with *non-digits* `[^0-9]`:

```
ls -1 --ignore=*[^0-9]*
```

> ***--ignore=PATTERN***
>                 do not list implied entries matching shell PATTERN

Comment: Not POSIX this.

Answer (score 0):

This command will be safest option always!

```
ls | grep -E '^[0-9]+$'
```

Adding few sample test cases for audiences to make it clear.

```
$ls
1       12222e      2       B.class     Test.java   file.sh     y.csv
1.txt       1a      A.class     Test.class  db_2017-08-15   file.txt
$ ls  | grep -E '^[0-9]+$'
1
2
```

Comment: Well `ls | grep -E '^[0-9]+$'` doesn't work either since default `ls` is not 1 file per line. You need to do `ls -1 | grep -E '^[0-9]+$'` to get a single column output from ls.

Comment: It's working fine for me. Tested in mac. See my answer, I have updated my results in answer

Comment: @dawg: If ls outputs to a pipe, it does it one line per file, so **this** is OK. However it is still not entirely correct, because the OP wanted to do a `ls -l`, so you would have to modify the regexp considerably. Also it breaks for the - admittedly pathologic case - that a file name contains a newline, which would grep see more than one input line for a single file.

Comment: User is  asking to display only the file name as mentioned in question.